solvefunction to get value to calculate Octave
I've recently found the solve function, which I see a potential in. However, I fail to see the output as usable.
For instance,
syms x

solve(x*sin(20)==5000)

produces the output:
warning: passing floating-point values to sym is dangerous, see "help sym"
warning: called from
    double_to_sym_heuristic at line 50 column 7
    sym at line 379 column 13
    mtimes at line 54 column 5

ans = (sym)

  7106000
  ───────
   413⋅π

Interesting. Because the answer is correct. Only problem is that I want to use this "value" not the equation in itself.
>> 7106000/(413*pi)
ans = 5476.8

Is there a way to get the solve function to actually produce the value I'm after?
I fail to see how I can use this value in further calculations without getting "access" to the calculated value.
I cannot see any flags or any other thing that could help me convert this value from symbolic to numerical...?

I realised my mistake.
I didn't set a variable to the equation.
using the same problem as above:
sol=solve(x*sin(20)==5000)

still gives the output:
warning: passing floating-point values to sym is dangerous, see "help sym"
warning: called from
    double_to_sym_heuristic at line 50 column 7
    sym at line 379 column 13
    mtimes at line 54 column 5

sol = (sym)

  7106000
  ───────
   413⋅π

If I write sol it provides with the following output:
>> sol
sol = (sym)

  7106000
  ───────
   413⋅π

However. If I write this
>> double(sol)
ans = 5476.8

Which means that I can now set a variable to it and use it for further equations.
Like this:
>> z = double(sol)
z = 5476.8

Which means that z is now the value I wanted in the first place.
>> z
z = 5476.8

